# JSON Parse not working in localhost

Tags: php, json

What is wrong with my code. if I remove the if statement all is working properly

```html
function approve(){

    global $wpdb;
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
       $app_status=$_REQUEST['app_status'];
       $from=$_REQUEST['match_from'];
       $to=$_REQUEST['match_to'];
       $role=$_REQUEST['role'];

       $approve = $wpdb->get_results("UPDATE  wp_hdoi_matching SET approval_Staus='yes' where match_from=$from and match_to=$to");
       if(!$approve){
          $msg = "success";
       }
       else
       {
          $msg = "error";
       }

       echo jason_encode(array('msg'=>$msg), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
       die();
   
   }
}
```

What is wrong with my code.. if I remove the if statement is sending

Comment: jason_encode? it should be json_encode I guess

Comment: It's json_encode not jason_encode

Comment: `What is wrong with my code` - poorly indented - makes it hard to read too

Comment: How about showing us what error you are getting? Also the function name is `json_encode` not `jason_encode`

Comment: `if I remove the if statement is sending` - which if statement, and when you say remove, do you remove the `if` and keep the body of the `if` or do you remove it all?

Comment: I suppose your problem is, that the client cant interpret the json you're sending. You _must only_ send the json without anything else. This is why it works when you remove the if statement (and don't send anything else). And of course `jason` as the others have said: typo here?